# Can I develop a Bip 3 Pro app with Zepp API

Tags: sony-smartwatch, zeppos

I see references to the GTR and T-Rex, but none for Bip 3 Pro. Should I bother trying to develop an app for the Bip 3 Pro? The app I want to write is not a health app, but a status application, showing updates accumulated from the Side app which will poll a remote service. Is that possible with the Zeppos API and Bip3 Pro? If I develop for the Bip3 Pro, will the app run on Pop, Band, Zepp E, GTR and T-Rex?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Bip 3 pro is not listed as a supported device with ZeppOS
The complete list can be found on [ZeppOS Supported Devices](https://docs.zepp.com/docs/reference/related-resources/device-list/) page